# Is a pointer used with a NSTimeInterval?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nstimeinterval

Do you use a pointer with a NSTimeInterval even though it is defined to be an int?
For instance do you use:
`NSTimeInterval *time` or 
`NSTimeInterval time`

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSTimeInterval` is a `double`, double-click the symbol while holding <kbd>Cmd</kbd> to see the `typedef`. Usually you will use it directly, but you can use a pointer for example to be able to change the value in a method call:

```
- (void) doSomethingLongAndReturnDuration: (NSTimeInterval*) duration
{
    CFAbsoluteTime start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
    …
    CFAbsoluteTime end = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
    *duration = end-start;
}
```

This is a weird example, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 3):

NSTimeInterval is typedef to double. There is usually no reason to use pointer

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't generally need/use a pointer with NSTimeInterval, so `NSTimeInterval time` should be just fine.